# D-Link DWM-156 3G Modem Ubuntu 13.04 not able to install

Tags: ubuntu, usb, 3g, modem

I asked this question on [`askunbutu forum`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347422/install-d-link-dwm-156-3g-modem-ubuntu-13-04) but didnt got a response from there. Its been around 2-3 weeks I posted this, but didnt got any response, hence now posting it over here. I have also gone through various forums and threads regarding this issue, but i'm still not able to have access to the internet.

The issue is that I bought a new D-Link 3G modem and it said it supports Linux. But after I installed it, I still can’t make the device work on Ubuntu 13.04.

I used the .deb file from the D-link modem 3g_modem_connect_D300_i386.deb (from the modem itself) but I was unable to configure it. I searched the Internet, they use dlinkusbmodem.deb file, which is a file from 1 year ago. Even after I dpkg it, I still don’t know how to proceed. I viewed [`this youtube`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NU8F3g1_Dc) and it doesn't work with this file version.

Please help me to rectify.

Comment: Can you not get help from the manufacturer?

Comment: I went to them, but those uneducated technicians doesn't know a bit of ubuntu. All they knew was few troubleshoot steps for windows and thats it.

Do you have any idea on the same?

Comment: I work in this area, and if I get a test device that doesn't work on a platform that it is supposed to work on, I would insist on speaking to second or third level support, until I get someone who knows about it. Your problem is, that you don't know how much testing has been done, very little by the sound of it, so it could be a problem that only the manufacturer can fix.  Does it produce any log files? Ask them how you can activate log files, and offer to produce log files for them.  Log files would probably be sent to a technical person.

Answer (score 0):

support staff says "we have no idea with **ubuntu**" *that sucks*, they will probably forward you a manual which is not worth following,
so you could
uninstall usb_modeswitch ,
then get the sources from http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/, make them and install them this will probably fix the problem.